# openrowset - How to select from a filename with white spaces?

Tags: sql, sql-server, openrowset

This is working :

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL','Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}; Extended Properties="text; HDR=YES; FMT=Delimited"','SELECT * FROM E:\folder\subfolder\myfile.txt')
```

This is not working because of the white spaces:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL','Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}; Extended Properties="text; HDR=YES; FMT=Delimited"','SELECT * FROM E:\folder\sub folder\my file.txt')
```

I tried with doubles quotes ("...") and with [...]

Thank you in advance for your tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation on OPENROWSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) specifically on the `query` (emphasis mine):

> 'query'
>
> Is a string constant sent to and executed by the provider. **The local instance of SQL Server does not process this query**, but processes query results returned by the provider, a pass-through query. [...]

In other words, it's not due to SQL Server that this pass-through query is not working.

The following two examples use the `DefaultDir` property in your provider string and should get your statement to work:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL','Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}; Extended Properties="text; HDR=YES; FMT=Delimited"; DefaultDir=E:\folder\sub folder;','SELECT * FROM [my file#txt]');
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL','Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}; Extended Properties="text; HDR=YES; FMT=Delimited"; DefaultDir=E:\folder\sub folder;','SELECT * FROM "my file.txt"');
```

Comment: Hello @TT. thanks for the input unfortunately replacing a white space with %20 does not work...