# OPENROWSET - issue with spaces in the file name

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

Using SQL Server 2016.

I am trying to read an Excel file using OPENROWSET. This works perfectly:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0 Xml; 
  HDR=YES; Database=D:\temp\my_filename_123.xlsx', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

Note that there are no spaces in the file name. However, the following will not work:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0 Xml; 
  HDR=YES; Database=D:\temp\my filename 123.xlsx', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

or using double quotes to enclose the whole path:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0 Xml; 
  HDR=YES; Database="D:\temp\my filename 123.xlsx"', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

The error is ".... cannot find 'Sheet1$'... etc.."

Please help.
Regards.

Comment: Is this a potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696374/openrowset-how-to-select-from-a-filename-with-white-spaces

Comment: No it's not. This is a totally different question.I am not using Microsoft Access driver but Ace OleDB. Moreover, I am not trying to open a text/csv file but an Excel 2010 xlsx

Comment: Tried this ? `SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0 Xml; 
  HDR=YES; Database=[D:\temp\my filename 123.xlsx]', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') `  (or maybe `Database=D:\temp\[my filename 123.xlsx]`)

Comment: I tried, it does not work...

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete XML from the Excel version specification:

```
select * 
    FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\temp\my filename 123.xlsx;HDR=YES', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

For me that works fine

Comment: Thanks Anton, but the post is 1.5 yr. old, anyways will keep in mind your suggestion :)